# Angular 11.0.9 getter in Model class not working

Tags: typescript, model, getter, angular11

I am using Angular 11.0.9 with NGRX and
subscribing successful to the store,
display data in the view using ngFor and interpolation.

All from the model is displayed but
I have a problem with 1 model property.

The problem:
In model class using getter to calculate the amount of 2 others
but not appears, no errors  $ {{o.amount}}

I've already checked the dolls is full and everything is fine

```
import { OrderDollsModel } from './OrderDollsModel'

export class OrderModel {
  _id: string
  creator: string
  creatorEmail: string
  dolls: OrderDollsModel[]
  date: Date
  status: string
  get amount(): number {
    return this.dolls.reduce((prev, cur) => prev += cur.price * cur.quantity, 0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably storing plain object in your store, not `OrderModel`.

Comment: :) it's not that I have models and data